# how can i distinguish between these objects(i.e FirstLevelEmployee and SecondLevelEmployee) and i want to print details of secondLevelEmployee?

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

In the below code , i have created both parent class and child class objects. These objects are stored in the arraylist. my question is how can i distinguish between these objects and i want retrieve only second level employee details.

```
package com.javahonk.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ListIterator;

class FirstLevelEmployee {
    int id;
    String name;
    double salary;

    FirstLevelEmployee(int id, String name, double salary) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}

class SecondLevelEmployee extends FirstLevelEmployee {
    int experience;

    SecondLevelEmployee(int id, String name, double salary, int experience) {
        super(id, name, salary);
        this.experience = experience;
    }
}

public class EmployeeDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<FirstLevelEmployee> emps = new ArrayList<>();
        emps.add(new FirstLevelEmployee(1, "aaa", 20000.00));
        emps.add(new FirstLevelEmployee(2, "bbb", 10000.00));
        emps.add(new FirstLevelEmployee(3, "bbb", 30000.00));
        emps.add(new SecondLevelEmployee(4, "zzz", 12000, 2));
        emps.add(new SecondLevelEmployee(6, "yyy", 45000.00, 5));
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `instanceof` and cast, i.e. `if(emp instanceof SecondLevelEmployee) { SecondLevelEmployee sl = (SecondLevelEmployee) emp; System.out.println(sl.experience); }`

Comment: Why don't you post it as an answer, @BretC?

Comment: I think this is a bad solution.  Casting means no polymorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do like this:

```
for(FirstLevelEmployee emp : emps){
     if(emp instanceof SecondLevelEmployee){
          System.out.println(((SecondLevelEmployee)emp).experience); 
     }
}
```

You will iterate over the array, and ask if the given element `emp` is a instace of `SecondLevelEmployee`. If its true, you'll print it by casting the `emp` to `SecondLevelEmployee`

Answer (score 1):

This design is less than optimal.

A better solution would have an Employee class with an experience attribute.  You could filter a collection by experience that way.

An Employee could transition over time after accumulating sufficient experience without having to change type or code.

I'd recommend rethinking this design.

Answer (score 0):

If you know Java 8, there is this option:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
             ArrayList<FirstLevelEmployee> emps=new ArrayList<>();
             emps.add(new FirstLevelEmployee(1, "aaa", 20000.00));
             emps.add(new FirstLevelEmployee(2, "bbb", 10000.00));
             emps.add(new FirstLevelEmployee(3, "bbb", 30000.00));
             emps.add(new SecondLevelEmployee(4, "zzz", 12000, 2));
             emps.add(new SecondLevelEmployee(6, "yyy", 45000.00, 5));

             emps.removeIf(e ->  e instanceof SecondLevelEmployee);

             System.out.println(emps);

       }
```